# What is the difference between passing &var to *var and var to var?

Tags: c, pointers, parameters, reference, linked-list

Basically, I want to know why this (passing the memory adress of list as parameter):

```
void init_lista (elemPtr *list) {
    *list = NULL;
}
int main(){
    elemPtr list;
    init_list(&list);
    //[...]
}
```

is different than this (passing just the content of list):

```
void init_lista (elemPtr list) {
    list = NULL;
}
int main(){
    elemPtr list;
    init_list(list);
    //[...]
}
```

**OBS:** elemPtr is a pointer type of a structure (`typedef struct elem *elemPtr`).

What I understand from `&`and `*`is that the first will get the var's memory adress and the latter will get the value referenced by it. Through this concept, both code sections should be equivalent, yet the first runs fine while the second compiles but gives me a runtime error. Why is that?

Comment: what is elemPtr? Is it typedef to some kind of pointer?

Comment: Any good enough C programming book explains that.

Comment: And explaining it depends upon your prior knowledge, and could take several pages.

Comment: The runtime error that you are seeing is because the second code sample doesn't change the value of `list` in `main()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this function

```
void init_lista (elemPtr list) {
    list = NULL;
}
```

`list` is a local variable of the function. You can imagine it like

```
void init_lista () {
    elemPtr list = NULL;
}
```

that is after exiting the function the variable will be destroyed. The original argument will not be  changed because it is passed to the function by value. So the function deals with a copy of the original object.

In this function

```
void init_lista (elemPtr *list) {
    *list = NULL;
}
```

there is passed pointer to the original object. So changing of the argument through this pointer will be done for the original object.

Comment: now I see. I thought that since `elemPtr` is a pointer type, C would treat it like a reference parameter-wise. I guess it doesn't work that way. thank you, @vlad.

Comment: @xVictor  It is reference  for the object it points to but not for itself.