# cannot understand this error

Tags: c, function, pointers

As I am a beginner in C

When I run the following C code :

```
#include<stdio.h>

void f(int *p)
{
    *p=3;
}

int main()
{
    int *p;
    f(&p);
    return 0;
}
```

I get these messages after compilation:

> 1) warning:passing arg 1 of 'f' from incompatible pointer type f(&p)
>
> 2) note: expected  'int *' but argument is of type 'int **'  void
>   f(int *p)

Comment: Welcome to SO. You need to understand pointer, pointer to a pointer and undefined-behavior.

Comment: .. and that pointers should actually *point* somewhere...

Answer (score 0):

Please note:

&p is the memory address of a variable

*p is the actual value of the variable

---

So what you are doing is:

In main: You are generating a variable pointer p. And you are passing this pointers address to a function f.

f thinks it gets a pointer as parameter but it gets a memory address and obviusly can't handle it.

More information is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28798322/what-is-the-difference-between-passing-var-to-var-and-var-to-var)

---

Hope I could help!

Comment: why cant the memory address be passed as the parameter to the function, isn't it similar to what is done in call by reference?

Comment: @JAISONJOHN Read the 2nd compiler message again. The function expects a `int*` (pointer to int) but you are passing a `int**` (pointer to pointer to int). You don't want to pass the **address of the pointer**, just do `f(p);`. Oh, and make sure `p` actually points to an `int` before you call the function.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a pointer to a pointer as an argument to a function expecting a pointer to an `int`. They're two different types and the compiler will complain.

There is another issue where you have the 'pointer' to the `int` but not the space allocated to store it. There are a couple solutions to this situation.

1)

```
{
    int q;         // add a new int, to which p points to. this allocates memory for an int
    int *p = &q;
    f(p);          // don't pass a pointer to a pointer, just the pointer
    return 0;
}
```

2)

```
{
    int p;         // have p be the int in the first place, not a pointer
    f(&p);         // your original call is unchanged and works now
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to think about this, because there are multiple levels of pointers.

Here's a simpler example.  This is what we might call "pass by reference":

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f(int *ip)
{
    *ip = 5;
}

int main(){
{
    int i = 7;
    printf("%d\n", i);
    f(&i);
    printf("%d\n", i);
}
```

Function `f` accepts a pointer to an int.  It modifies that int.  In `main`, we have an int variable `i`.  We take the address of that variable using `&`, and pass the resulting pointer to function `f`.  In this way, function `f` is able to modify `i` in the caller.  Note that function `f` takes a pointer to something, and that what it takes a pointer to is the type of `i` in the caller -- in other words, pointer to int.

Now let's look at another example.  This time, instead of manipulating an `int` by reference, we're going to manipulate a pointer variable, a `char *`.  (We're going to end up dealing with pointers to pointers.)

```
void g(char **sp)
{
    *sp = malloc(10);
    strcpy(*sp, "oranges");
}

int main(){
{
    char *s = "apples";
    printf("%s\n", s);
    g(&s);
    printf("%s\n", s);
}
```

Again, function `g` accepts an argument by reference.  Again, function `g` is able to modify a variable in its caller.  Again, the pointer type accepted by `g` is a pointer to the type being manipulated.  Since the type being manipulated is "pointer to char", function `g` accepts a pointer to pointer to char, or `char **`.

But the code you posted is sort of a mixture of the two.  Your function `f` accepts an int pointer, just like mine, and it tries to use that int pointer to modify an int variable in the caller.  But then, in your `main` function, the variable you're trying to modify isn't an int, it's a pointer to int, or `int *`.

When you call

```
f(&p);
```

you're starting with a pointer-to-int, `p`, and you're taking its address with `&`, resulting in a pointer-to-pointer-to-int.  But then you;re calling function `f`, which expects a pointer-to-int.  That's what the compiler is trying to tell you with the messages

> warning: passing arg 1 of 'f' from incompatible pointer type
>   note: expected 'int *' but argument is of type 'int **'