# Is there no pointer to a single character in the C language?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main() {
    char* c;

    scanf(" %c", c);

    printf("%c\n", *c);
    return 0;
}
```

Why this results in a segmentation fault ?
Can't I create a pointer to a single character?

Comment: It has to point somewhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can, but your pointer `c` doesn't actually point anywhere. That means when `scanf` will dereference the pointer you will have [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

This is one place where you use the *address-of* operator `&`:

```
char c;
scanf(" %c", &c);
```

---

And some nitpicking about your phrasing "create a pointer to a single [anything]". That's really what *all* pointers are, pointers to a single something.

A string is typically seen as a pointer to `char`, but the pointer actually only points to the *first* character in the string. That the program handles it as a string is just a convention to treat the first character as the first element of an array, which is terminated by a special character.

Comment: But, if i need to edit this c value in a funtion, how can I do it ?

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main() {
 char* c;
 
 scanf(" %c", c);

 printf("%c\n", *c);
 return 0;
}

void functionx (char c) {
 c = 'a';
}

Comment: If you have another question, ask it as another question.

Comment: @albm Use the same technique for your function, let its argument be a pointer, and use `&c` when passing the character. This is emulating something called *pass by reference*.

Comment: @albm See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50880518/cannot-understand-this-error/50880989#50880989) to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50880518/cannot-understand-this-error).

Comment: @SteveSummit I understand now, I was trying to attribute a value (Using scanf) to an undeclared memory address. Because I just declared a c pointer, but it still pointing to nothing.
Thanks!